# functions: Error: Request failed with status code 401, twitter api auth error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, twitter, oauth-2.0

I am writing code to automatically tweet, and it used to work just fine. After implementing some code changes and a cron job it began giving me this error. My code uses the twitter api v2 and auth2.0. as well as firebase/firestore and node.js to create and host servers to run the functions.

> !  functions: Error: Request failed with status code 401
> at createError (C:\Users\EASYHOME\OneDrive\Desktop\AI twitter bot\functions\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
> at settle (C:\Users\EASYHOME\OneDrive\Desktop\AI twitter bot\functions\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
> at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\EASYHOME\OneDrive\Desktop\AI twitter bot\functions\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:322:11)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)

I am pretty sure it has to do with the authentication, I tried regenerating the access tokens and every other token, but to no avail. I did notice that on the twitter developer platform it says my access token and secret was "Created with Read Only permissions"

Here is the code in question

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const dbRef = admin.firestore().doc("tokens/demo");

const TwitterApi = require("twitter-api-v2").default;
const twitterClient = new TwitterApi({
  clientId: "client id goes here",
  clientSecret: "client secret goes here",
});

const {Configuration, OpenAIApi} = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
  organization: "org goes here",
  apiKey: "api key goes here",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);


const callbackURL = "http://127.0.0.1:5001/twbot-ad868/us-central1/callback";

// STEP 1 - Auth URL
exports.auth = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const {url, codeVerifier, state} = twitterClient.generateOAuth2AuthLink(
      callbackURL,
      {scope: ["tweet.read", "tweet.write", "users.read", "offline.access"]},
  );

  // store verifier
  await dbRef.set({codeVerifier, state});

  response.redirect(url);
});

exports.callback = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const {state, code} = request.query;

  const dbSnapshot = await dbRef.get();
  const {codeVerifier, state: storedState} = dbSnapshot.data();

  if (state != storedState) {
    return response.status(400).send("Stored tokens do not match!");
  }

  const {
    client: LoggedClient,
    accessToken,
    refreshToken,
  } = await twitterClient.loginWithOAuth2({
    code,
    codeVerifier,
    redirectUri: callbackURL,
  });

  await dbRef.set({accessToken, refreshToken});

  const {data} = await LoggedClient.v2.me();

  response.send(data);
});

exports.tweet = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, respone) => {
  const {refreshToken} = (await dbRef.get()).data();

  const {
    client: refreshedClient,
    accessToken,
    refreshToken: newRefreshToken,
  } = await twitterClient.refreshOAuth2Token(refreshToken);

  await dbRef.set({accessToken, refreshToken: newRefreshToken});

  const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * prs.length);

  const nextTweet = await openai.createCompletion("text-davinci-001", {
    prompt: prs[i],
    temperature: 1,
    max_tokens: 64,
  });

  const {data} = await refreshedClient.v2.tweet(
      nextTweet.data.choices[0].text,
  );
  console.log(data);
});

exports.tweetHourly = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("0 * * * *")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
      const {refreshToken} = (await dbRef.get()).data();

      const {
        client: refreshedClient,
        accessToken,
        refreshToken: newRefreshToken,
      } = await twitterClient.refreshOAuth2Token(refreshToken);

      await dbRef.set({accessToken, refreshToken: newRefreshToken});

      const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * prs.length);

      const nextTweet = await openai.createCompletion("text-davinci-001", {
        prompt: prs[i],
        temperature: 1,
        max_tokens: 64,
      });

      const {data} = await refreshedClient.v2.tweet(
          nextTweet.data.choices[0].text,
      );
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: `I am pretty sure it has to do with the authentication`: correct a 401 indicates *the client request has not been completed because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the requested resource*

Comment: `it says my access token and secret was "Created with Read Only permissions"` - that only applies to OAuth 1.0A and you’re implementing OAuth 2.0 in your code with `tweet.write` as part of the permissions you are requesting, so while it looks like an auth issue, the access token and secret on the developer portal should not apply in this case.

Comment: You mentioned that this used to work fine, what changed between then and now?

Comment: @AndyPiper I added cron jobs and deployed the code, I dont think I changed much in regards to the original code